# how to convert dynamic contents of html page to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

In html page some tags are dynamically created using jquery and contents are loaded from msql db using jquery and php.
I want convert this dynamic page to pdf.
I have tried following code but it generate pdf of static part of html page.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
//html code and internal css, javascript used in external file with jquery library
<?php
  include('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
  $contents = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($contents);
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream('file.pdf'); 
?>
```

So how to store contents of dynamic html page in a php variable after processing it ( using javascript/php ) and convert it to pdf usin dompdf or other converter.

Comment: Can't be done unless you actually execute the JS code. PHP is not a JS interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at wkhtmltopdf.  I've had good results with getting it to render google charts, which are built dynamically from a javascript api.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 1):

As Marc said, you have to read generated DOM with javascript.. something like `$('html').html()` and then post it to php to generate pdf

Answer (score 0):

This may not meet exactly what you are looking for, but [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) could be what you need.  Since PHP is a server-side technology, you will have a difficult time getting it to process any client-side javascript.  wkhtmltopdf scans the page, javascript and all, then generates a pdf file on the server.  Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a tool like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to directly generate a page as a PDF.  It will run javascript and generate the page as WebKit would render it.